# Como chamar função PHP em outra função AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs

Tenho a seguinte function em AngularJS:

```js
angular.module("fluxo").controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

var mostraTodasContasEntradas = function () {
    $http.get("php/index.php").success(function (data){

    });
}

//mostraTodasContasEntradas();
```

});

```php
<?php
require_once "../con/conexao.php";
require_once "../classes/contaEntrada.php";
require_once "../classes/contaSaida.php";

$entrada = new contaEntrada();
$saidas = new contaSaida();

$entrada->mostraContasEntrada($id_empresa);
```

Essa function vai chamar uma outra function em uma classe em php que necessita de uma id.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O seu objetivo é só obter o dado do php? No caso, um resultado de um select?

Comment: Exato @CelsomTrindade.

Comment: Cria o objeto no index.php e chame o método e retorne o json.

Comment: Já estou fazendo isso.
To postando essa parte na descrição do post.

Só que nessa classe, não vai ter só essa função, terão outras tb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso, recomendo que você crie um `factory` ou seja, um serviço. Desse modo, sempre que você precisar desses dados, seja nesse ou em outro controller, você pode somente fazer referência a ele de modo mais fácil e modular.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
.factory('factCliente', ['$http', function($http) {
    //esse aqui faz um get simples
    var _getData = function() {
        return $http.get("data/index.php");
    };

    //esse aqui faz o carregamento do dado enviando algum atributo para o php processar
    var _getData2 = function(id) {
        return $http.post("data/index.php", id);
    };

    return {
        getData: _getData,
        getData2: _getData2,
    }
}])
```

E ai para chamar essas funções no seu controller, você faria assim:

```
.controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, factCliente) {

var mostraTodasContasEntradas = factCliente.getData();

//Ou então
var idCliente = {id: meuId},
    mostraTodasContasEntradas = factCliente.getData2(idCliente);
});
```

Deste modo, se você precisar dos dados do cliente em outro controle, basta injetar o factory dele, ou seja `factCliente` no seu novo controller, e chamar a função. Exemplo:

```
.controller('OutroCtrl', function($scope, factCliente) {
    $scope.maisCliente = factCliente.getData();
})
```

### Edit:

A ideia disso é que você **não** utilize o seu $http dentro do controller, pois imaginemos a seguinte situação:

Você possui 7 controllers que façam esse mesmo get do php. Se por algum acaso você mudar o nome do php, ou mudar a estrutura dele de modo que você precise mudar no seu AngularJs, você NÃO vai precisar alterar em 7 lugares diferentes, estando propício a mais erros.

O modo como você fez funciona, apenas para PEGAR o dado bruto, digamos que seja um select do php simples, através do primeiro exemplo (o _getData): `select * from 'tabela'`, ou seja, irá pegar todos os dados.

O segundo método (o _getData2) que mostrei ele utiliza o POST, pois primeiro você envia o dado para depois selecionar o que você precisa, exemplo: `select from 'tabela' where id = $meuId`.

Conseguiu compreender a lógica?

Comment: Celsom, tenta montar isso, em cima do código que postei, pois não sei onde eu devo fazer essa correção, a partir de onde.

Comment: Atualizado a resposta.

Comment: Ainda estou meio perdido.
Altero tudo, por isso que você postou?

Comment: Editei a resposta @GustavoSevero

Comment: Sim, entendi, vou tentar.